# Windows 8 metro app single-sign-on using Windows Live SDK

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, single-sign-on, windows-live

I am building Windows8 metro app and need to implement single sign on and connecto to skydrive.

Code from various sources that I referred (mentioned at the end)...

```
    WL.init({ scope: "wl.signin" });

    WL.login().then(
                function onSuccess(session) {
                    var session = WL.getSession();
                    if (session.error) {
                        document.getElementById("infoLabel").innerText =
                            "Error signing in: " + session.error;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("infoLabel").innerText =
                            "Signed in.";
                    }
                }, 
                function onError(error) {
                    document.getElementById("infoLabel").innerText =
                            "Error signing in";
                }
        );
```

I am getting following error (`onError` function) - "**The application requesting authentication tokens is either disabled or incorrectly configured**"

I referred following links and libraries. One of the [links](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/ff09e5ca-0ede-430c-971d-ee9db49a94cf) is suggesting app registration. I am having developer registration completed, do I have to register the app inorder to achieve single sign on metro app?

Thank you.

- [Sample app with steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/06/26/best-practices-when-adding-single-sign-on-to-your-app-with-the-live-sdk.aspx)
- [Need app registration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/ff09e5ca-0ede-430c-971d-ee9db49a94cf)
- [WL.login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh550845.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to register your Windows 8 App here if you want to work with Live Connect: https://manage.dev.live.com/build?wa=wsignin1.0

Good luck!